# Ошибка при сборке ядра на Android

Tags: android, linux, kernel, ядро

Хочу поставить kali nethunter на xiaomi redmi 5a,ядра с поддержкой nethunter нет,поставил прошивку aex nougat, а ядро решил сам сделать по всевозможным мануалам с гитхаба.Нашел вроде как исходник, но там нет defconfig файла для моей мобилы(кодовое название riva  а процессор msm8917),скрин defconfig файлов https://pp.userapi.com/c856016/v856016023/6b799/DoY6xGNa_W0.jpg

https://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/tree/riva-n-oss типо исходник

Пропатчил командами

wget http://patches.aircrack_ng.org/mac80211.compat08082009.wl_frag+ack_v1.patch

patch -p1 < mac80211.compat08082009.wl_frag+ack_v1.patch

Прописываю make msmcortex-perf_defconfig , так как мне сказали что если нет твоего дефконфига то создают новый из этого

дальше make menuconfig, выставил нужные параметры, сохранил , make , начинается процесс и потом вылезает ошибки про rndis_ipa_trace.h вот ссылка на скрин, если тут фотку не загрузит.
 https://pp.userapi.com/c852024/v852024720/146305/bs1fE9dMho4.jpg

Я так понял надо искать нормальный исходник где есть defconfig под мой телефон, но на xda тоже нет.Подскажите как решить эту проблему?
Использую Ubuntu 18.04 LTS[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы, похоже, вообще не понимаете, что происходит и что нужно делать. Начните хотя бы с правильной ветки для вашего телефона, если она вообще там есть.

Comment: (В сторону: zOMG, на такое старое ядро там тысяча запросов и отчётов о проблемах!)